# Was there ever a Pokemon game based off the Orange Islands?

Tags: pokemon

Did they ever release a Pokemon game dealing with the Orange Island League?

I was thinking and I remembered that each Pokemon anime series followed the same route as the games as far as getting the badges, but I wanted to know if they ever released a Pokemon game that dealt with Ash's adventures in the Orange Islands.

If they did what is the name of the game? If they didn't, why not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no game located in the Orange Islands. Perhaps the closest game would be Fire Red/Leaf Green where the player could explore Sevii Islands. There are arguments that this was inspired by the Orange Islands, but I haven't found any proof.

There have been player modded games fitting in with the Orange Islands - [Example](http://www.pokecommunity.com/showthread.php?t=225147), but no official release. [Reference](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/Orange_Islands)

[According to this answer on another site](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100525190130AANMhtE), the Orange Island plot was half-hearted and this probably meant that there was no real push for a related game on that end.

Answer (score 0):

By the end of the first season, Pokemon: Gold and Silver (Johto games) was still unreleased so the anime had to create a filler arc involving the GS ball and the Orange League to stall time. The Pokemon anime is based on the games and therefore could not go straight ahead and do the Johto saga if the game it's based on isn't released yet.

The Orange Islands is probably loosely based on the Sevii Islands from FireRed and LeafGreen but still debatable.

Answer (score 0):

There are no official games made by Nintendo about the Orange Islands. Some romhacks have been made/are under construction about them though.:

Pokemon Orange Islands (Complete)
https://forum.silphco.io/threads/pokemon-orange-islands.69/

Pokemon Orange
https://forum.silphco.io/threads/pokemon-orange-hoty-2017.67/

Pokemon Naranja:
https://www.pokecommunity.com/showthread.php?t=54546

Answer (score -1):

I think it's more plausible that there was no game made because  there was no real idea how many pokemon there was at the time(150 kanto, 250 jhoto). also there was only four gym leaders each with diffrent obstacles to go through the challenges would be to hard to mimic on the gameboy though it would be easy and fun on the ds. The other factor that puzzles me is the orange league champion Drake uses a dragonite, drake is the same name they used in the kanto games and the jhoto games he is the charater you face after the elite four and he records you and your pokemon just as they did for ash after he defeated the orange league champion. In red blue yellow is known as chapion in jhoto he is also known as the dragon master. HE wears a pokeball around his neck just video game drake meaning that they must be the same person. So in a way they even though they don't have orange island gym leaders they still have the chapion drake which makes the game partly related to orange island. Though everything is just speculations And no one will no for sure but what we know is that the longer they continue to air Pokemon the more fans will become confused.

Answer (score -1):

There is one game on Orange Islands. The name of the game is Pokemon Naranj.

Comment: It's a hack ROM made by fan, though